# How should i change function content ? PHP

Tags: php, function

I want to add `time()` function some minutes.

How should I do that?

```
function time() {
    return time() + 60*10;
}
```

die:

```
Fatal error: Cannot redeclare time() in /home/matan/domains/only4gamer.com/public_html/Framework/config.php on line 20
```

Please HELP! THANKS

Answer (score 1):

You cannot re-declare php built-in function names. Instead, use

```
function _time() {
return time() + 60*10;
}
```

or any other name that is not already reserved by php.

For more information on built in functions, check this: http://php.net/manual/en/indexes.functions.php

Answer (score 0):

PHP has already a time function: http://php.net/manual/fr/function.time.php
You cannot create a function with the same name than a PHP native function.
You need to find another name;